# Run 4 statement async and block UI till all completes

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I want to execute four statements async and then block the UI till all of then completes execution.

```
private void Test()
{
    //Run Async
    System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task1);
    System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task2);
    System.Threading.Thread t3 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task3);
    System.Threading.Thread t4 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task4);

    t1.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-1 started....");

    t2.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-2 started....");

    t3.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-3 started....");

    t4.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-4 started....");

    while( !v1 || !v2 || !v3 || !v4)
    {
        //Block UI
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("All task completed....!");
}
```

Where `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v4` are global boolean variables which I have set to `true` when `Task1()`, `Task2()`, ... completes.

How can I achieve this functionality with async/await ?

In my winform application, when the application loads, I have a function which fills all the tables in Dataset which takes more time, if all they run async it may reduce some time, I don't want the application to start before loading dataset.

**I want something like this...**

```
private void Test()
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    //Run Async
    System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task1);
    System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task2);
    System.Threading.Thread t3 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task3);
    System.Threading.Thread t4 = new System.Threading.Thread(this.Task4);

    t1.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-1 started....");

    t2.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-2 started....");

    t3.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-3 started....");

    t4.Start();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task-4 started....");

    while (!v1 || !v2 || !v3 || !v4)
    {
        //Block UI
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("All task completed....! " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

can i do the same with async/await ?

Comment: Block the UI how? Stop it from drawing completely? Or just stop it from responding to user input? If the latter, that's typically achieved by displaying a modal dialog that explains what's going on and why the UI is blocked or, alternatively, just disabling everything in the UI. Either way, your question is lacking any useful detail, and has too many different possible answers. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, explain what that code does, what _precisely_ you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ it is you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4);
```

Comment: Don't you think we should use WhenAll() ?

Comment: Task.WhenAll() returns pointer to the collee function, i don't want to do than, i want it to stop there

Comment: It does NOT return control flow to the calling method. It will create a new task that completes only when all child tasks are completed. Just add await on that task and you'll get what you want.

Comment: i have tried it, but it will starts executing the statements after await in main function from where i have called `test()`

Comment: Your Test() should also be an async method returning Task. And you should call it like await Test(). If you call it directly from main() which could not be async, then call it like Test().Wait();